# How Can You See How Days Have Passed in Minecraft Bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My friend and I have a survival world in Minecraft bedrock that we have had for a while, and while I doubt there is, I was just wondering if there was a way to see how in-game days have passed, either in the files or with a mod. Thank you!

[image]

I could not find anything when looking it up, other than things for Java Edition.

Comment: On Java, pick 'Statistics' from the ESC menu, 'Time Played' will give time in in-game days you spent in the world. Not quite 'how much time passed in the world' and I'm not sure Bedrock has a counterpart, so just posting as a comment.

Comment: @Sf. yep sadly we don't have statistics :(

Comment: Do you play on PC or another kind of device (consoles, smartphones...)? If you have access to the world file, maybe you can open it with an external tool. No idea if that's possible or even if Minecraft actually records the current in-world date...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer: This method uses commands, so create a copy of your world and use it there, or else you will no longer receive achievements in your world.**

---

The `time query` [command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/commands/time) can be used to check the in-game days that have passed since you created your world. You can also check the number of ticks that have passed since you created your world.

---

### Usage:

`/time query day`

*Shows the number of in-game days since you created your world. (Each day lasts 20 minutes, 10 minutes of day, 10 of night.)*

`/time query gametime`

*Shows the number of [ticks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tick) since you created your world. (One tick is 1/20 of a second.)*

---

**How to create a copy of a world:**

1. Open the setting for your world by pressing the "pencil" button. (You need to leave first)  [image: Press the "pencil" button to open the world settings]
2. Click on the ***Game*** settings tab.[image]
3. Scroll down to the bottom, and click on the ***Copy World*** option. [image: Scroll to the bottom to find the Copy World option, and click it]
4. You should now see the copy of your world in the worlds menu, named: "Copy of `Name of your world`"

Comment: If I use /time query day on a copy of my Minecraft world, will it have the same days even if I created a copy months after I created the original world?

Comment: Yes, the copy is exactly the same as your original world, except for the name, and the time data will be carried over.

Comment: Thank you so much! If I do /time query day, it shows 598. Is that the amount of ingame days?

Comment: Why is it marked as a spoiler?

Comment: I wanted to compact it- that didn't work.

Comment: Glad I could help! Yes, that should be the number of in-game days, a day counts as one day-night cycle.